# Speed/Performance Characteristics of blocking vs Non-Blocking winsock

Tags: performance, sockets, tcp, winsock

Is there in general a speed or performance difference in blocking and non-blocking Winsock TCP Sockets? 
I could get the differences of both sockets but there isn't a detailed performance comparison between the two types.

Comment: If anything, I would tag this question as C not C++.

Answer (score 8):

Because it isn't about speed. The operations `write` and `read` are just **memory copying** in disguise. All they do is copy data to and from the kernel, respectively. I.e. **they don't actually send or receive anything**.

The blocking vs nonblocking feature asks: do you prefer these operations to block until completed or to return -1 and `EAGAIN` in case they can't be performed immediately ? For example, you read from a socket but there's nothing in the receive buffer. Do you prefer to have `recv` hanging until something comes along or to return -1 `EAGAIN` ?

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: It's quite a disguise with IOCP, where user buffer pointer arrays are communicated into the kernel with the WSASend/WSARecv calls. There is still some data movement, but I'm guessing that the NIC hardware buffers can be DMA'd directly into the user space buffers - cuts out one level of miserable copying.

Comment: The system calls can be very expensive, even though the underlying final operation is coping memory.

Answer (score 8):

In my experience non-blocking winsock operations are slightly slower but much more scalable. The fact is that you need to make two system calls plus some dispatching at the application level when you perform nonblocking I/O (with IOCP) and one system call if you use blocking I/O. If you have many concurrent connections, nonblocking I/O is much faster because of more scalable architecture if implemented well.

If you need to transfer data from point to point with max bandwidth - use blocking I/O. If you need to handle many concurrent client connections - use nonblocking I/O. Don't expect too much from any of them.

In general this is more about "event-driven vs threaded" server architecture then "blocking vs nonblocking". There is no universal server architecture that can be used in any situation. It depends on application.